# Is it legal to fly this approach in Bahrain if the VORTAC is out of service?

Tags: instrument-flight-rules

Can I fly [the VOR/DME/ILS RWY 33R approach](http://www.bahrainaims.com/eAIP/Publications/AIRAC05-18/2017-08-17-AIRAC/graphics/13354.pdf) at [Bahrain/Isa Airbase (OBBS)](https://skyvector.com/airport/OBBS/Bahrain-Isa-Airbase-Airport) if the OBBS VORTAC is out of service?

Comment: Link in question didn't work for me; [this one](http://www.bahrainaims.com/eAIP/Publications/AIRAC05-18/2017-08-17-AIRAC/graphics/13354.pdf) does.